# How to append text to a TextArea using ObservableList

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, model-view-controller

I'm trying to implement a client-server JavaFx Application which exchange messages. I'm trying to append text (server side) to a TextArea from a thread which handle client requests passing through methods placed in the Model which comunicate with controller.

**For example:**
In the thread which handle client requests, If user successfully logged in **-->** I call the method setLogMessages("user logged in.") which is in the model and set my observableList **-->** Strings are sent to the controller which should append them to the TextArea.

I wrote this code:

**Server Model**

```
public class ServerModel {

        private ObservableList<String> observableLogMessages;

        //other code

        /**
        * This method starts the server connection.
        */
        public void startServerConnection() {
           serverRequests.serverConnection();
        }

        public void setLogMessages(String logMessage) {

          observableLogMessages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
          ArrayList<String> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
          messagesList.add(logMessage);
          observableLogMessages.setAll(messagesList);
        }

        public ObservableList<String> getLogMessages() {
            return observableLogMessages;
        }

        public void changeObserver(ListChangeListener<String>messagesChangeListener) {
           observableLogMessages.addListener(messagesChangeListener);
        }

// other code

}
```

**Server Controller**

```
public class LogController {

private final ServerModel serverModel = ServerModel.builServerModel();

@FXML
private ResourceBundle resources;

@FXML
private URL location;

@FXML
private AnchorPane logAnchorPane;

@FXML
public TextArea logTextArea;

@FXML
private JFXButton logClearButton;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    logTextArea.setEditable(false);

    serverModel.changeObserver((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> messagesChange) -> {
        if (messagesChange.next() && messagesChange.wasAdded()) {
            ObservableList<String> logMessages = serverModel.getLogMessages();
            for (int i = 0; i < logMessages.size(); i++) {
                logTextArea.appendText(logMessages.get(i)); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Thread which handle client requests**

```
public class ServerRequests {

   //other code 

   public void serverConnection() {
      ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    try {
        //initialize the Server Socket class
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
    }
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("waiting for clients...");
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest(clientSocket);
            Runnable runnable = clientRequest;
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerRequests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

 public class ClientRequest extends Thread {
      // other code
      public ClientRequest(Socket socket) throws ClassNotFoundException {
             // other code
      }

 @Override
    public void run() {

      // if user successfully login add, this message to the TextArea.
      serverModel.setLogMessages("User successfully connected.");
    }
    // other code
  }
}
```

If I run this code, the message "User successfully connected." **is not added to the TextArea** and I also tried to print the observableList size in the model which remains always 1 even if I try to add multiple messages.
I read many similar question on here and tried to fix by using Platform.runLater() but nothing still happen to my TextArea and I can't understand why!

**UPDATE**

I tried to add a button on my log just to see if on click, it returns a message. I found out that I can't even click it becuase everything get stuck (server side) and it gives me "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working" error message. What can cause this?

[image]

**LogController UPDATE AFTER SUGGESTIONS**

```
public class LogController {

//serverModel
ObservableList<String> logMessages;

@FXML
private AnchorPane logAnchorPane;

@FXML
private TextArea logTextArea;

@FXML
private Label serverLogLabel;

@FXML
private JFXButton logClearButton;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    logTextArea.setEditable(false);
    logTextArea.appendText("Appending");   //This append text correctly
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        serverModel.changeObserver((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> messagesChange) -> {
            if (messagesChange.next() && messagesChange.wasAdded()) {
                ObservableList<String> logMessages = serverModel.getLogMessages();
                for (int i = 0; i < logMessages.size(); i++) {
                    logTextArea.appendText(logMessages.get(i));
                }
            }
        });
    });
    logClearButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Clear clicked");
    });

}
```

}

Still not printing on TextArea and still get stuck on opening + "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working" error message.

Comment: you _must not_ change anything in the scenegraph off the fx application thread: in your particular context that's updating the text in the area in a listener to the log list which is changed on a background thread. Wrap that setting into a Platform.runlater() should work

Comment: @kleopatra Which setting are you talking about? logTextArea.appendText(logMessages.get(i)); or serverModel.setLogMessages("User successfully connected."); ? I tried to add all the serverModel.changeObserver() of the LogController in the Platform.RunLater but still not working. Could you provide me an example please? maybe I'm using Platform.runLater() in the wrong way.

Comment: you only have one ListChangeListener to the list of logmessages .. ;)

Comment: change your example - and make sure it's a  [mcve]

Comment: @kleopatra uploaded the changes made to the code!

Comment: that's wrong - you don't have to wrap the registering of the listener but the line where the listener is updating the textArea

Comment: @kleopatra Uploaded a solution, I would be happy to have your feedback since I'm not sure this is good coding! Thank you!

Comment: repeating: the runnable in Platform.runlater _must not_ be list.addListener() instead it _must be_ textArea.appendText  .. and best not to be happy with accidentally working code, you have to understand the whys, always :)

Comment: @kleopatra yup, I tried this solution but still not working! I left only serverModel.getLogMessages(); inside the serverModel.changeObserver() and textArea.appendText() in Platform.runLater().

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue I can notice is you are creating a new observable list everytime for a new message and setting a list to your observableList using setAll. So with this implementation, you can never have the observableList to have more than 1 item.

You need to create the observableList instance outside and use addAll() or  add the message direct to the observableList.

```
private ObservableList<String> observableLogMessages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();    
public void setLogMessages(String logMessage) {
       ArrayList<String> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
       messagesList.add(logMessage);
       observableLogMessages.addAll(messagesList);
    }
```

or

```
private ObservableList<String> observableLogMessages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public void setLogMessages(String logMessage) {
   observableLogMessages.add(logMessage);
}
```

Comment: You were right! My bad..now the Model's ObservableList is filled with Strings correctly -still need to find out why it doesn't print on my TextArea.